# how to use vbs variables in html tags

Tags: html, variables, vbscript, hta

I'm making an hta app and I'm trying to add in an option to change the color schemes. I've been trying to use a variable in the tag. ex:Color1 instead of black etc..
But everything is just default colors

Heres part of what I wrote in the vbs section:

```
Sub changecolor    
Colorbutton = gray    
Colorbuttontext = black    
Colortextbox = black    
Colortext = aqua    
End sub
```

Here's a snippit of the HTML I have:

```
 <input type="text" color="Colortext">     
 <input type="button" color="Colorbutton">
```

I already have a drop down menu that uses onChange="changecolor" and I've tested and I know its getting to the sub

I've tried putting Colortext.value or Colorbutton.value, but everything still changes to the default colors. Does the tag not recognize the variable so it Just skips it reverts to the default colors?

If anyone knows how to fix this let me know, thanks!

P.s. I'm kindof a novice so if you could keep the answers as dumb as possible that would be fantastic, thanks again

Comment: Do you have to use VBScript? You will need to manipulate the DOM and this is a lot easier with JavaScript instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the DOM API to manipulate a webpage, and the visual appearance of elements is controlled by CSS, though some legacy presentational attributes still work (e.g. `<body background>`).

I recommend using JavaScript over VBScript in all cases where possible, not least for the more expressive syntax, but also for the greater flexibility and programming options enabled by its prototype-based nature, compared to VBScript's limited typing system.

You can use JavaScript in a HTA just like VBScript, just use `<script type="text/javascript">` instead of `<script language="VBScript">`.

Note that you cannot use reliably use "Edge mode" in HTAs, so new developments in browsers over the past few years will not work reliably, such as new CSS3 effects or DOM changes. When you are in Edge mode, HTA-specific markup will be ignored by the HTA shell, so you cannot set a custom window icon or titlebar text while in Edge mode (I feel this is a bug, but AFAIK Microsoft has no plans to fix this).

In JavaScript, you would do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var colorButton = document.getElementById("colorButton");
    colorButton.onclick = function() {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
        textInput.style.color = "black"; // foreground (text) color
        textInput.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    };
};
</script>

<input type="text" id="textInput" />
<button id="colorButton">Click me</button>
```

Comment: My pal knows JS he can walk me through it. Ill have to add Java to the list of languages I need to learn, it'd deffinatly make doing stuff like this a whole lot easier! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ColeRichardson [tag:java] and [tag:javascript] are completely different, learning [tag:java] would not help much here.

Comment: @Lankymart hah! i meant JS

Answer (score 1):

You can also, take a look at this HTA example **Multiplication Table (I * J)**:
It dynamically generates an HTA Multiplication Table (I * J) with colors

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Table de Multiplication ( I * J ) © Hackoo Crackoo 2013</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
ID="Table de Multiplication © Hackoo Crackoo 2013"
APPLICATIONNAME="Table de Multiplication © Hackoo Crackoo 2013"
SCROLL="yes"
SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
WINDOWSTATE="Maximize"
icon="CALC.exe"
>
</head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="MSThemeCompatible" CONTENT="YES">
<center><body text=white bgcolor=#1234568 TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1" RIGHTMARGIN="1">
Nombre de Lignes : <input type="text" onFocus="this.style.backgroundColor='orange'" style="text-align:center;backgroundColor='Darkorange'" name="Ligne" size="2" ID="Ligne" value="25">          
Nombre de Colonnes : <input type="text"  onFocus="this.style.backgroundColor='orange'"style="text-align:center;backgroundColor='Darkorange'" name="Col" size="2" ID="Col" value="25">          <input type="Submit" style="text-align:center;" Value="Afficher la Table de la Multiplication" onclick="Calculer()"><br>
<center><span id="Erreur"></span></center>
<center><span id="Data"></span></center>
<center><span id="Sig"></span></center>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
Option Explicit
Sub Window_OnLoad()
    Ligne.style.backgroundcolor = "DarkOrange"
    Col.style.backgroundcolor = "DarkOrange"
    Calculer()
End Sub

Sub Calculer()
    Dim NbrLigne,NbrCol,StrHTML,i,j,Signature
' Table de multiplication
' --------------------------------------------------------
' NbrCol : le nombre de colonnes
' NbrLigne : le nombre de lignes
    NbrCol = Col.value
    NbrLigne = Ligne.value

    If IsNumeric(Ligne.Value) = False  Then
        Erreur.InnerHTML = "<b><font color='RED' size='6'>ATTENTION ! IL FAUT CHOISIR UN NOMBRE ENTIER NUMERQUE !</font></b>"
        Data.InnerHTML = ""
        Ligne.style.backgroundcolor = "red"
        Sleep "3"
        Ligne.Value = ""
        Erreur.InnerHTML = ""
        Ligne.style.backgroundcolor = "DarkOrange"
        Ligne.Focus  
        Exit Sub
    End If    

    If IsNumeric(Col.Value) = False  Then
        Erreur.InnerHTML = "<b><font color='RED' size='6'>ATTENTION ! IL FAUT CHOISIR UN NOMBRE ENTIER NUMERQUE !</font></b>"
        Data.InnerHTML = ""
        Col.style.backgroundcolor = "red"
        Sleep "3"
        Col.Value = ""
        Erreur.InnerHTML = ""
        Ligne.style.backgroundcolor = "DarkOrange"
        Col.Focus
        Exit Sub
    End If        
' --------------------------------------------------------
' on affiche en plus sur les 1ere ligne et 1ere colonne
' les valeurs a multiplier (dans des cases en couleur)
' --------------------------------------------------------
    StrHTML = "<br><table border='1' style='border-collapse: collapse' bordercolor='#111111' width='100%'><thead>"
    StrHTML=StrHTML & "<tr>" '1ere ligne (ligne 0)
    StrHTML=StrHTML & "<th style=""background:#CCCCCC;"">i*j</th>"
    for j=1 to NbrCol
        StrHTML=StrHTML & "<th style=""background:DARKORANGE""> "& j &" </th>"
    next
    StrHTML=StrHTML & "</tr>"
    StrHTML=StrHTML & "</thead>"

    StrHTML=StrHTML & "<tbody>"
' lignes suivantes
    for i=1 to NbrLigne step 1
        StrHTML=StrHTML & "<tr>"
        for j=1 to NbrCol
' 1ere colonne (colonne 0)
            if (j=1) then
                StrHTML=StrHTML & "<td style=""background:DARKORANGE""><center>" & i & "</center></td>"
            end if
' colonnes suivantes
            if (i=j) then
                StrHTML=StrHTML & "<td style=""background:RED"">"
            else
                StrHTML=StrHTML & "<td>"
            end if
' -------------------------
' DONNEES A AFFICHER dans la cellule
            StrHTML=StrHTML & "<center>" & i*j & "</center>"
' -------------------------
            StrHTML=StrHTML & "</td>"
        next
        StrHTML=StrHTML & "</tr>"
        j=1
    Next
    Data.InnerHTML = StrHTML
    Sig.InnerHTML = "<br><center><img src='"&Chr(104)&Chr(116)&Chr(116)&Chr(112)&Chr(58)&Chr(47)&Chr(47)&Chr(110)&Chr(115)&Chr(109)&_
    Chr(48)&Chr(53)&Chr(46)&Chr(99)&Chr(97)&Chr(115)&Chr(105)&_
    Chr(109)&Chr(97)&Chr(103)&Chr(101)&Chr(115)&Chr(46)&Chr(99)&Chr(111)&Chr(109)&Chr(47)&Chr(105)&_
    Chr(109)&Chr(103)&Chr(47)&Chr(50)&Chr(48)&Chr(49)&Chr(49)&Chr(47)&Chr(48)&Chr(55)&Chr(47)&Chr(50)&_
    Chr(51)&Chr(47)&Chr(47)&Chr(49)&Chr(49)&Chr(48)&Chr(55)&_
    Chr(50)&Chr(51)&Chr(48)&Chr(55)&Chr(52)&Chr(49)&_
    Chr(52)&Chr(48)&Chr(49)&Chr(51)&Chr(49)&Chr(49)&Chr(48)&_
    Chr(52)&Chr(56)&Chr(53)&Chr(48)&Chr(54)&Chr(52)&Chr(49)&_
    Chr(57)&Chr(46)&Chr(103)&Chr(105)&Chr(102)&"' alt='"&Chr(104)&Chr(97)&_
    Chr(99)&Chr(107)&Chr(111)&Chr(111)&Chr(102)&Chr(114)&Chr(64)&_
    Chr(121)&Chr(97)&Chr(104)&Chr(111)&Chr(111)&Chr(46)&Chr(102)&Chr(114)&"'</img></center>"
End Sub

Sub Sleep(Secs)' Fonction pour faire une pause car wscript.sleep ne marche pas dans un HTA
    Dim fso,objOutputFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Dim tempName : tempName = "Sleeper.vbs"
    If Fso.FileExists(tempFolder&"\"&tempName)=False Then
        Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
        objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
        objOutputFile.Close
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName &" "& Secs*1000,1,True
End Sub
</script>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something simular.
After generating a list of workstations from Active Directory, I check if those workstations are online. If they are, StrResult will return "Success".

Hope this helps

```
    IF StrResult="Success" THEN
        strColor = "Green"
        ELSE
        strColor = "Red"
    END IF
  '------------ some more code ...
  strHTML = strHTML & "<td>" & "<Font color=" & strColor & ">" & AGNR.value & "</font> </td>"
```