# VB script,...code for creating table in html

Tags: vbscript, qtp

i want a code in vb script, which will create tables 5*2 rows n columns which are static in nature. then another in dynamic, as give input of rows that is 5...those many rows to be created.

Comment: nice goal... And what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Take a look at this ==> [How to use vbs variables in html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32644052/how-to-use-vbs-variables-in-html-tags)

Comment: I assume you meant [tag:vbscript] not [tag:vb.net]?

Comment: I'm not sure how the tag QTP applies to this question.

Answer (score 1):

try to use loops (for example while), show your code....

```
Imports System

Public Module Module1
    dim table as string
    dim i as integer
    dim k as integer
    Public Sub Main()

        i = 0
        table = "<table>"
        while i < 5
            k = 0
            table = table & "<tr>"
            while k < 2
                table = table & "<td> Row: " & i+1 & " Column: " & k+1
                table = table & "</td>"
                k = k + 1
            end while
            table = table & "</tr>"
            i = i + 1
        end while   
        table = table & "</table>"

        Console.WriteLine(table)
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: I don't think the [tag:vb.net] tag should have been included. But that's what happens when you jump the gun attempting to answer before anything has been clarified. Let's face it the question is poor at best with no [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).